# Neos 2.1: Dynamic Landingpage

Tags: content-management-system, neoscms

I want to create dynamic landingpages in neos.
I thought best the way to do it is to create a shortcut und place some landingpages as children. Now the shortcut should select one of them. Here is the problem part. How can I tell Neos which child it should show.

I thought I can write a custom NodeShortcutResolver and a custom Shortcut Node. but I dont know how to tell neos to use the custom NodeShortcutResolver.

Hope you can help or give some suggestions to solve it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deliver multiple versions of your landingpage depending on some constraints (language, country, usergroup or whatever), use a dimension.
A dimension don't have to be a translation but you can combine a "language" dimension and a "myLandingPageDimensions" dimension.

Comment: No its not a dimension problem. For example I show a Landingpage to someone depending on their visits on other pages throught cookies. Has he been on page A -> place a cookie for that page, next time he visits the same page show slightly different content if that cookie was set. Hope that was understandable :-).

Comment: and that is the usecase of a dimension. If you want to show different version of a node depending on some constraint (for example a cookie value) use a dimension. In your example you have a "visitor" dimension with values ['vistedA', 'visitedB'] etc.

Comment: Okay, I think I got your point and you are right. But when I use dimensions I have to use another Uri segment right, or is that Hideable?

Comment: Okay found the answer http://neos.readthedocs.org/en/stable/CreatingASite/ContentDimensions.html bottom of the page